# Animating template changes in Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, tween

I have looked, but am unable to find anything which makes me think I'm approaching this the wrong way.

When I update the content in a template, or display a new template, I want to animate the transition. Currently the content switches but I'd like to be able to use Greensock or similar to perform the change. I have Greensock working on elements fine, but not on templates.

I'd show code but I'm not sure where to begin. I'll update when I've at least made a start.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can google about undocumented Meteor _uihooks used for example here:

https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum
https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum-iron-router

Comment: That pointed me to the direction I needed to figure it out, thanks :)